# React Native FlatList only gets updated when TextInput or Picker changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to dynamically add text from an input field and a picker to a FlatList in React Native. The problem I have is that the FlatList doesn't get updated as soon as I hit the button.

The item does get added to the list eventually but only after I trigger the onChangeText of the text input or the onValueChange of the picker element.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

CreateSetScreen = () => {
    const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Placeholder');
    const [pickerValue, setPickerValue] = React.useState("1");
    const [listValues, setListValue] = React.useState([]);
    
    joinData = () => {
        listValues.push({"content": value, "category": pickerValue, "key": listValues.length.toString()});
        setListValue(listValues);
    }

    return(
        <View>
            <TextInput 
                style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                value={value}
            />
            <Picker
                selectedValue={pickerValue}
                style={{height: 50}}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => setPickerValue(itemValue)}
            >
                <Picker.Item label="Kategorie 1 - 1%" value="1" />
                <Picker.Item label="Kategorie 2 - 10%" value="2" />
                <Picker.Item label="Kategorie 3 - 20%" value="3" />
                <Picker.Item label="Kategorie 4 - 29%" value="4" />
                <Picker.Item label="Kategorie 5 - 40%" value="5" />
            </Picker>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{backgroundColor:'#DDDDDD'}}
                onPress={() => joinData()}
            >
            <Text>Add Item!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <FlatList
                data={listValues}
                renderItem={({item}) => (<Text>{item.category}: {item.content}</Text>)}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
    

export default CreateSetScreen;
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When do you want to add to those in the `FlatList`? Like when you change picker item, text from the input will be added to `FlatList`. Won't it?

Comment: Yeah it does get added when I change the picker item or the text but I want it to be added when I press the button.

Comment: Have a look at my answer I've given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `.push()` works in the setter function from React Hooks but It doesn't. Rather than returning the array itself, `.push()` returns the length of the array after modification.

On the other hand, `.concat()` works to update state, that is `.concat()` creates a new array and then returns the changed array.

So just change your `joinData` function a little bit in this way.

```js
const joinData = () => {
    setListValue(listValues => listValues.concat({ "content": value, "category": pickerValue, "key": listValues.length.toString() }));
}
```

Comment: My pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a key extractor to your `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
  data={listValues}
  renderItem={({item}) => (<Text>{item.category}: {item.content}</Text>)}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still only gets added when I change the picker item or the text value